# Zodb process Killed after reading multiple fs

Tags: pandas, memory, zodb

I have used ZODB BTrees to store some data (~1-2GB per file). I created the ZODB files using:

```
storage = FileStorage(os.path.join(zodb_dir, 'trainPatches.fs'))
db = DB(storage)

connection = db.open()
root = connection.root()

root.patches = BTrees.OOBTree.BTree()
# take columns from a pandas data frame and insert into zodb 
for col in df.columns:
    root.patches[col] = df[col]

transaction.commit()

db.close()
connection.close()
```

and now I am reading them (and converting back into dataframes) using:

```
        db = DB(FileStorage(file_name))
        connection = db.open()
        root = connection.root()
        # this is the key to the BTree that the files we're saved as
        pp = root.patches
        p_list = list(pp.items())

        # from ZODB is stored as a list of tuples, need to separate out names and data
        column_names = [names[0] for names in p_list]
        data_ = [names[1] for names in p_list]

        # insert into data frame
        patches_df = pd.DataFrame()

        for i, c in enumerate(column_names):
            patches_df[c] = data_[i]

        connection.close()
        db.pack()
        db.close()
```

But after reading ~30 of them, the process is Killed in terminal. I'm new to using ZODB but perhaps the memory is being eaten up by this write/read sequence?

Comment: Why would you cast your data on read into a list?  Enumerating that requires memory enough to store the *WHOLE* list.  This is not a ZODB problem, AFAICT (aside from the fact that OOBTree.items() returns lazy sequences and therefore does not act like dict.items(), you may want to use OOBTree.iteritems() or just iterate through the lazy sequence returned by OOBTree.items()).

Comment: Also, if a process is killed by the operating system for OOM, most operating systems logging mechanism will have some kind of entry for that.